# Como sacar el valor de una Clase y ponerlo en una variable de JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Necesito ayuda con mi código.

Esta es solo una parte del código y es la que no he podido resolver, lo que necesito es lo siguiente:

Necesito que la variable NUMERO1 tenga el valor que esta extrayendo JavaScript que quedo almacenada en cord1.

La parte de JavaScript es la mayoría JQuery, esto lo uso para poder sacar el numero de link que es una api, este numero generado por la api siempre va estar cambiando.

Y necesito que este dato que queda guardado en cord1, pase a numero 1.

Solamente necesito eso, si alguien puede ayudarme se lo agradecería.
.
.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "https://api.thingspeak.com/channels/1300758/fields/1/last.html"
    }).then(function(data) {
        console.log(data)
       $('.cord1').append(data);
    });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Hello jQuery</title>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="hell.js"></script>
       
    <body>
        <div>
            <h1 style="background-color: aqua;"> 
            <p class="cord1">El primer numero es </p>
            </h1>
            <script>
                 var numero1=document.getElementsByClassName("cord1")[0].innerText;
                  console.log("hola "+numero1);
            </script>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Buenas, en esta linea: `var numero1=document.getElementById("cord1");` estás realizando la selección de elemento por Id, no por clase.
Prueba algo así: `document.getElementsByClassName("cord1")[0].innerText`